# remove focus "phisically" from edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an editText like:

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/card_summary_name_tv"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"                          
     android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
     android:imeOptions="actionDone"
     android:inputType="text"
     android:singleLine="true" />
```

Now when user press done button on keybard, editText should lose focus, and i perform an action:

```
        mCardNameEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                mCardNameEditText.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

mCardNameEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                performAnAction();
            }
        }
    });
```

now it happen that with clearFocus(), performAction() is called, but editText still have cursor blink on it, so when i close fragment that contains editText, it lost focus again and performAction is called again. How can i fix it?

Comment: clearFocus() sets the focus back to the first focusable view in your layout. That means if your ET is the only view in your layout, it does not not work.

Comment: i've other views inside layout, but that is the only EditText

Comment: try to set the focus to another view.

Comment: i've already try, by creating a dummy and invisible textView by invoking requestFocus() on if, but cursor still remain on first edtiText

Comment: Are you sure that `actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` is `true`?

Comment: yes, performAction is launched well